# Make function that supports currying AND the traditional multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

> Question: How would you make this work?
>   add(2)(5); // 7
>   add(2, 5); // 7

I am trying to solve the question above:
I know that the first solution uses currying and would be implemented as follows:

```
var add = functoin(x){
return function (y){
return x+y;
};
};
```

while the second is jsut your normal function:

```
var add = functoin(x,y){
return x+y;
};
```

Is there a way to make both work at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a higher-order function to wrap other functions with that behaviour.

This kind of function is often called `curry`, and it comes with many libraries ([lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#curry), for example).

`curry` returns a new function that checks whether all the expected arguments have been supplied. If they have, it calls `originalFunction`. If not, it returns a partially applied function,

This implementation uses [`Function#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) to test call arity, so it works with any number of arguments.

```js
function curry (fn) {
  return function (...args) {
    if (args.length >= fn.length) {
      return fn.call(this, ...args)
    } else {
      return curry(fn.bind(this, ...args))
    }
  }
}

function add (x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

// You can curry any function!
const curriedAdd = curry(add);

console.log(curriedAdd(1, 2)); // 3
console.log(curriedAdd(1)(2)); // 3
console.log(curriedAdd(1));    // a function
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `Function#length` doesn't include optional arguments, and this implementation doesn't do anything special to help with `this` - like usual, it's determined by how the curried function is called.

Comment: If you want to do real currying that works for more than 2 parameters, you should do `return curry(fn.bind(null, ...args))`

Answer (score 3):

You could inspect the amount of arguments passed in and return one or the either depending on it:

```js
function add(a, b) {
  if (arguments.length == 2) {
    return a + b;
  }
  return function(b) {
    return add(a, b);
  }
}

console.log(add(2)(5)); // 7
console.log(add(2, 5)); // 7
```

Comment: Better: `function(b) { return add(a, b); }` so that you don't need to duplicate the code

Comment: @Bergi yup, I actually had that first then switched it since I figured it was simpler without recursion. Switched it back now.